# Getting Auth Code from URL in C# to consume Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am going to consume a Web API, which need 3 legged authentication. In my case I need a auth code, Which I always get when I visit a website and than
in response a login page get display. On which I need to enter username password and I redirected to other URL which contain this auth code in URL.

How can I get this code and automate this process in C#.

URL to Hit at step 1:

https://example.com/auth/login?client_id=tnlFfqWw5e2CKsh65tyAgbFh2k0d3ptK&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://dm.renesan.com/Login.aspx?renesanp=PCC

Then this redirected to other page where I need to enter Username and password.
Screesnhot 1

Then this page gets directed to another URL which contain auth code.
Screesnhot 2[image]

Comment: Are you trying to use an http client to automate an OAUTH Authorization Code Flow? I wouldn't. The whole point of this OAUTH login is to verify that a human is giving authorization.

Comment: You should be redirecting back to your service.

Answer (score 0):

Follow PCC's developer guidelines for OAuth, there's no way to bypass the 2nd leg (user login at PCC for the callback), you'll need to create a pop up to launch the login process for the user to proceed; ie: your app -> cURL to PCC's login (pass secret, scope) -> user enters PCC creds, signs in -> redirect back to your app with the code; at this point you can trade off for a JWT Token and refresh it when needed (the return contains both bearer and refresh token).

I was a part of the PCC dev program for 3 years I can tell you it's very simple as long as you follow the steps (first section, oAuth in the docs); it tells you exactly what to do - fire off a call to request code back to your redirect URI, your redirect URI is the handler for the code (in this case return it back to your application by adding a listener to when the redirect is complete). Login and read the docs @ https://developer.pointclickcare.com/spa/login